# Couldn't Get Data From Form with multipart/form-data

Tags: c++, forms, http, c++11, cgi

so I wrote a CGI program using C++ but it won't get any data that's encrypted using `multipart/form-data`. Here's how I tried to do it in a nutshell:

```
char delim (10); // the delimiter
std::string inps; // will store the result

while (std::getline(std::cin, inps, delim)) { /* do nothing? just read the input in loop */ }

// then this will interpret the result.
```

I tried using `x-www-urlencoded` and it works, it can receive the form input. But somehow it won't read anything with `multipart/form-data`.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed!
Turns out I have to register each of lines I got from `std::getline()`!!

```
char delim (10); // the delimiter
std::string inps; // will store the result

while (std::getline(std::cin, inps, delim)) { /* push_back string to a vector */ }

// then this will interpret the result.
```

Comment: Can't accept my own answer, will check again soon. ;)